# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error during bulk insert to mysql database?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
package textfileimport;
import catalog.Root;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class Textfileimport {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {


        Root oRoot = null;

        PreparedStatement oPrStmt = null;

        FileReader in = null;

        BufferedReader br=null;

        try {
            oRoot = Root.createDbConnection(null);  
            in = new FileReader("C:/Users/i2cdev001/Desktop/snomedinfo_data.txt");      

            br = new BufferedReader(in);
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){

                String [] splitSt =strLine.split("\\t");
                String dat1="",dat2="",dat3="",dat4="",dat5="",dat6="",dat7="",dat8="",dat9="";
                dat1=splitSt[0];
                dat2=splitSt[1];
                dat3=splitSt[2];
                dat4=splitSt[3];
                dat5=splitSt[4];
                dat6=splitSt[5];
                dat7=splitSt[6];
                dat8=splitSt[7];
                dat9=splitSt[8];        

                String sql = "INSERT INTO textfiledata (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) VALUES( ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                oPrStmt = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(sql);
                oPrStmt.setString(1, dat1);
                oPrStmt.setString(2,dat2);
                oPrStmt.setString(3, dat3);
                oPrStmt.setString(4, dat4);  
                oPrStmt.setString(5, dat5);
                oPrStmt.setString(6, dat6);
                oPrStmt.setString(7, dat7);
                oPrStmt.setString(8, dat8);
                oPrStmt.setString(9, dat9);
                oPrStmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            System.out.println("sucessfully imported");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmt);
            br.close();
            in.close();
            oRoot = Root.closeDbConnection(null, oRoot);
        }
    }

}
```

iam trying to read around 1383709 lines from a text file and insert them into my mysql table.I get a java heap space error when i run this application.how do i solve this problem.I have already tried setting  VM arguments in the configurations menu in eclipse with no success.

Comment: Is your prepared statement being closed? My guess is that is what is consuming all of the memory. For each iteration it increases but never decreases and sooner or later you run out of space.

Comment: bufferedstream is fine. no issues there. Use batching and check the transactions are committing after every batch.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions, instead of using string operations and buffered reader.
This should use less memory.
A Scanner is safe if not multithreaded and can be used with no synchronization.

Also try using a batch execute, something like below.

```
final FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
final Scanner inputScanner = null;
final String sql = "INSERT INTO textfiledata (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) VALUES( ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
oPrStmt = db.prepareStatement(sql);
db.setAutoCommit(false); 
try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
    inputScanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
    while (inputScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputScanner.nextLine();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("\\t");
        int i =1;
        while(s.hasNext()) {
         String dat = s.next();
         oPrStmt.setString(i++,dat);
        }
        oPrStmt.addBatch();
        s.close();
    }
    if (inputScanner.ioException() != null) {
        throw inputScanner.ioException();
    }
    oPrStmt.executeBatch();
    db.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
       if (fileInputStream != null) {
         fileInputStream.close();
       }
       if (inputScanner != null) {
         inputScanner.close();
       }
       oPrStmt.close();
       db.close();
}
```